# How to send data serially from atmega328p to pc using serial communication?

Tags: c, embedded, teraterm, atmega32

i'm trying to send data continuously from atmega328 to pc using mx232 and i'm using tera term to display the data coming from com5. The problem here is that the sent data is always the same character regardless of which character i send from my atmega. the code is below and attached a photo of the output in tera term

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
#define RBC 51
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void define_inputs_and_outputs(){
    DDRC |= (DDC5);
    DDRD |= (1<<DDD1);
}

void init_serial_transmit(){
    UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ00) | (1<<UCSZ01);
    //set baud rate
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = RBC;
    
}

void serialPutString(char* string, unsigned int size){
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = (int) string[i];
    }
    
}

void stop_serial(){
    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = 0;
    UCSR0C = 0;
    UDR0 = 0;
}

void init_serial_receive(){
    return;
}

void blink(){
    PORTC |= (1<<PORTC5);
    _delay_ms(300);
    PORTC &= ~(1<<PORTC5);
    
}


int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */
    define_inputs_and_outputs();
    init_serial_transmit();
    //_delay_ms(10000);
    
    while (1){
        UDR0 = 8;
        serialPutString("moha",4);
        blink();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check your baud rate in Tera Term?

Comment: i have chaecked it and it's 9600. it's in my code nearly 9615, does this make any difference?

Comment: If the baud rates don't match from the device and your computer you will see garbage output which appears to be happening in your image just off a first glance

Comment: i have tried making the baud rate 38400 to narrow down the difference to be as small as possible but this time the cursor in teraterm advances but nothing appers on the screen, the cursor just moves to right

Comment: Both sides of the link must be using exactly the same baud rate. What baud rate did you set your Atmega device up for? 9615 is not a standard baud rate and unlikely to be supported on any terminal device. See http://www.rjhcoding.com/avrc-uart.php.

Comment: i have tried all possible combinations and tried to use an external oscillator of value 16mhz but every calculation for the value to be put in the ubrr yield a fraction so, i try to round it and put the answer in ubrr . for example, for 16mhz f_cpu i put 103 inside ubrr to get 9600 baud rate does this cause this problem? the tera term now displays just 00000000